# GPA calculator only gives the answer 1.29?

Tags: python, traceback

```
#Author: Zian Lin
#Date: March 22th 2016
#Purpose: Calculating your GPA.

#Variables
grades = []
finalgpa = []
number = 1
rank = 0
counter = 0
boolean = 0
lower = [0, 60, 64, 67, 70, 74, 77, 80, 84, 87, 90, 94]
upper = [59, 63, 66, 69, 73, 76, 79, 83, 86, 89, 93, 100]
gpa = [0, 0.7, 1, 1.3, 1.7, 2.0, 2.3, 2.7, 3, 3.3, 3.7, 4]

start = str(input("Do you want to calculate your GPA?"))

#Collects all the grades
if start == "Yes" or "yes":
  while number <= 7:
    answer = input("What is your grade for class " + str(number) + "?")
    if int(answer) > 100 or int(answer) < 0:
      print("Please input a valid number.")
    else:
      grades.append(answer)
      number = number + 1

#Displays grades
print("These the grades you've inputted.")
print(str(grades[:]))

#Convert grades to GPA
if counter != 7:
  if int(grades[counter]) >= int(lower[rank]) and int(grades[counter]) <= int(upper[rank]):
    #Scroll through
    finalgpa.append(gpa[counter])
    counter = counter + 1
    boolean = 1
  if boolean == 0:
    rank = rank + 1

#Average all the GPAs
def averager(a, b, c, d, e, f, g):
  return (a+b+c+d+e+f+g)/7

#Print final GPA
result = averager(finalgpa[0], finalgpa[1], finalgpa[2], finalgpa[3], finalgpa[4], finalgpa[5], finalgpa[6])
print("Your GPA is " + str(result) + "!")
```

For my computer class, I had to make something in Python, so I decided to make a GPA calculator. Everything above #Print final GPA theoretically works fine, but when I try to average the final GPA, it gives me this error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 47, in 
IndexError: list index out of range

Why is this happening?

Comment: `finalgp` a is not fully populated, only `grades` have length of 7

Answer (score 0):

Your `if counter != 7` block is wrong.

1. First of all, you want to iterate each grade
2. You also want to iterate each rank
3. `finalgpa.append(gpa[counter])` is wrong. You want `gpa[rank]` not counter, since counter is the index for grades not gpa,

Here is fix:

```
#Convert grades to GPA
for grade in grades:
  for rank in range(0, len(gpa)):
    if grade >= int(lower[rank]) and grade <= int(upper[rank]):
        finalgpa.append(gpa[rank])
        break
```

An easier way to do average would be taking in a array, say `finalgpa`, then `sum(finalgpa)/len(gpa)`.